# To find the swap space,system running information,cpu information and RAM usage

Tags: linux

I am testing few systems where i have been asked to find Whats CPU's the system is running on and how much RAM does it currently use. I have solved the issue using the command top.

```
top - 01:49:56 up  5:21,  2 users,  load average: 0.10, 0.18, 0.23
Tasks: 185 total,   3 running, 182 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  4.1 us,  1.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 94.2 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   2945180 total,  2788784 used,   156396 free,   639912 buffers
KiB Swap:   262140 total,     9408 used,   252732 free,  1216156 cached

      PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND           
     1893 aritrada  20   0 1432m  97m  28m S   9.3  3.4   2:36.60 compiz            
     1121 root      20   0  132m  25m 5328 S   5.6  0.9   5:39.31 Xorg              
     3030 aritrada  20   0 1025m 315m  38m R   5.6 11.0  13:31.12 firefox           
     2416 aritrada  20   0  526m  19m  12m S   1.7  0.7   0:09.72 gnome-terminal    
       18 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.3  0.0   0:00.41 ksoftirqd/3       
     1984 aritrada  20   0  400m  11m 8424 S   0.3  0.4   0:03.65 bamfdaemon        
     2006 aritrada  20   0  536m  27m  11m S   0.3  1.0   0:12.46 unity-panel-ser   
     6644 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.3  0.0   0:00.69 kworker/u:0       
     6861 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.3  0.0   0:00.71 kworker/0:0       
     6951 root      20   0 24800 1640 1164 R   0.3  0.1   0:00.14 top
```

I have also been asked to find the swap space  and i used the command swapon -s

The output of swapon -s has been pasted below:

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/host/ubuntu/disks/swap.disk            file        262140  10264   -1
```

I have also been asked to find what are the drivers loaded which i did using the commad lsmod. The output the lsmod command has been pasted below:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
nls_utf8               12557  1 
isofs                  39842  1 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32007  1 
joydev                 17457  0 
snd_hda_codec_idt      70209  1 
btusb                  18334  0 
coretemp               13400  0 
kvm_intel             132759  0 
kvm                   414070  1 kvm_intel
arc4                   12529  2 
brcmsmac              531848  0 
mac80211              539908  1 brcmsmac
brcmutil               14755  1 brcmsmac
cfg80211              206566  2 brcmsmac,mac80211
cordic                 12535  1 brcmsmac
dell_wmi               12681  0 
sparse_keymap          13890  1 dell_wmi
bnep                   18140  2 
dell_laptop            17369  0 
dcdbas                 14438  1 dell_laptop
microcode              22803  0 
snd_hda_intel          33491  3 
snd_hda_codec         134212  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                96580  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_rawmidi            30512  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
rfcomm                 46619  12 
bluetooth             209199  22 btusb,bnep,rfcomm
intel_ips              18049  0 
parport_pc             32688  0 
psmouse                95552  0 
serio_raw              13215  0 
lpc_ich                17061  0 
ppdev                  17073  0 
uvcvideo               76749  0 
snd_seq                61521  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
videobuf2_core         32851  1 uvcvideo
videodev              120309  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
videobuf2_vmalloc      12860  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13368  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
bcma                   35656  1 brcmsmac
snd_timer              29425  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
snd                    78734  16 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
soundcore              15047  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18484  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
mei                    40690  0 
i915                  520519  8 
drm_kms_helper         46784  1 i915
drm                   275528  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915
video                  19335  1 i915
wmi                    19070  1 dell_wmi
mac_hid                13205  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                46345  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
hid_generic            12493  0 
usbhid                 46947  0 
hid                   100366  2 hid_generic,usbhid
r8169                  61650  0
```

and last but not the least i am trying to find how many hours has the system been running which i tried using the command

```
01:58:12 up  5:29,  2 users,  load average: 0.28, 0.32, 0.27
```

Kindly let me know whether the command used by me for each activities mentioned above is correct or not. Also kindly let me know if there are some better alternatives for performing the above mentioned activities.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is more suitable for Unix branch.

Anyway, for parts 1 and 2 (CPU, memory and swap), you may also use

- `cat /proc/cpuinfo`
- `cat /proc/meminfo`
- `free -m` (read `man free` for complete list of options)
- `vmstat`